# Deleting from the start of a line to a colon regex(notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to delete from the start of a line to the first colon. The dark gray area designates the area I am trying to get rid of.

[.txt file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkFDF.png)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Seems like a rather trivial task to me.

Comment: @SebastianProske a ton of googling, and searching through stackoverflow.  Here is a list of a few of the commands I tried. .+(\"Line"\*\:)
\Line*\:
^(*)
^*
^*(:)
Line*'
Line *'  I am sure there are things that you have difficulty with that seem pretty trival to me as well.

Comment: I hope during searching through stack overflow you learned a few things about how to ask questions and don't use an image next time. I can only recommend doing some basic regex tutorials (you should get everything needed for this task quite quickly).

Comment: @SebastianProske What is wrong with my question? I understand if it's frowned upon if i use images. I saw someone use one and I thought it would be okay.  I do get downvoted when i asked questions, I don't know why.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react should help you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^.*Line \d+:(.*)$
```

and replace by:

```
\1
```

Make sure that .matches new line is not checked